# Why does ShowDialog() show old message?

Tags: c#, showdialog

Why does ShowDialog() show old message?

I entered a "test message" for my ShowDialog, then changed it to a new message. But it is still showing the "test message"

New Code

```
private void addButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //MessageBox.Show("Debugging Add Test Button", "My Test Application",
        //MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);

        //Display Add Alarm form
        AlarmForm alarmForm = new AlarmForm();

        //Display alarmForm instance, assgn the results to a Dialog result
        DialogResult dialogResult = alarmForm.ShowDialog();

        //Check return value, and extract data
        if (dialogResult == DialogResult.OK)  // Add Alarm 
        {

            //Extract Alarm information from the Form using the accessor
            Alarm alarm = alarmForm.Alarm;
            //Add the alarm object to our list
            _alarms.Add(alarm);

            //Update the Listbox
            refreshAlarmList();
        }
    }
```

Old Code

```
private void addButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
        MessageBox.Show("Debugging Add Button", "My Application",
        MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
    }
```

Any ideas on what is causing this? I have tried removing the code, adding in the new message, and commenting it out.

Comment: Do you have any code to show, or should we use our crytall ball?

Comment: Crystal Ball does sound appropriate, sounds like there is magic at work.

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like a caching issue. I'd try clearing your browser cache and trying again.

Comment: I must be missing something. Is there any method like *ShowDialog* in javascript?